# Error converting audio recording to Base64 String

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script which is designed to convert an audio recording to a Base64 string which then sends to a Google Dialogflow agent.

This works fine in the editor but brings up an error on a WebGl Build.

This is the code:

```
AudioClip recorded =  StopRecord();
            Debug.Log("Recorded Successfully");
            byte[] audioBytes = WavUtility.FromAudioClip(recorded);
            Debug.Log("audioByte Success");
            string audioString = Convert.ToBase64String (audioBytes);
            Debug.Log("audio string is:" + audioString);
            SendAudio(audioString);
```

The recording process is successful and the log shows: "Recorded Successfully", however, I then get the following error:

```
OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
  at System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.Double value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Convert.ToInt16 (System.Double value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Convert.ToInt16 (System.Single value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WavUtility.ConvertAudioClipDataToInt16ByteArray (System.Single[] data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WavUtility.WriteFileData (System.IO.MemoryStream& stream, UnityEngine.AudioClip audioClip, System.UInt16 bitDepth) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WavUtility.FromAudioClip (UnityEngine.AudioClip audioClip, System.String& filepath, System.Boolean saveAsFile, System.String dirname) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at WavUtility.FromAudioClip (UnityEngine.AudioClip audioClip) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at DF2ClientAudioTester.OnButtonRecord () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (UnityEngine.EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1].Invoke (T1 handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ReleaseMouse (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, UnityEngine.GameObject currentOverGo) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMousePress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule+MouseButtonEventData data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMouseEvent (System.Int32 id) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMouseEvent () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_LogException(Exception, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogException(Exception, Object)
UnityEngine.Logger:LogException(Exception, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogException(Exception)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ReleaseMouse(PointerEventData, GameObject)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMousePress(MouseButtonEventData)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent(Int32)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()


_JS_Log_Dump @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1772
$WebGLPrintfConsolev(LogType, char const*, void*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42be4db
$InternalErrorConsole(char const*, ...) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42bf414
$DebugStringToFilePostprocessedStacktrace(DebugStringToFileData const&) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42bf211
$DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42be71c
$Scripting::LogExceptionFromManaged(ScriptingExceptionPtr, int, char const*, bool, Scripting::LogExceptionFromMangedSettings const*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x421a76f
$DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_LogException(Il2CppObject*, Il2CppObject*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x424043b
$dynCall_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db16a
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15492
$DebugLogHandler_Internal_LogException_mE01E7F56C7441415DDACFFFAC2C4E6FE15B76DB5 @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x28aba20
$dynCall_viii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db1e6
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_viii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15525
$DebugLogHandler_LogException_mF66A663A86BF5D412BC9A4B3F92DA5CF61049F08 @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x28abd9e
$InterfaceActionInvoker2<InputDeviceDescriptionU5BU5D_t8856839C0F01DD680E9A308A4AB77EA5AEF1ACF5*, int>::Invoke(unsigned short, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*, InputDeviceDescriptionU5BU5D_t8856839C0F01DD680E9A308A4AB77EA5AEF1ACF5*, int) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x230c70
$dynCall_viiiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db1c8
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_viiiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15613
$Logger_LogException_m591AF39F0886DA44666068EDBBD3CCF07623CFBB @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x28d6481
$InterfaceActionInvoker2<InputDeviceDescriptionU5BU5D_t8856839C0F01DD680E9A308A4AB77EA5AEF1ACF5*, int>::Invoke(unsigned short, Il2CppClass*, Il2CppObject*, InputDeviceDescriptionU5BU5D_t8856839C0F01DD680E9A308A4AB77EA5AEF1ACF5*, int) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x230c70
$dynCall_viiiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db1c8
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_viiiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15613
$Debug_LogException_m82E44FEC6B03BC34AFC2CAF6583051570C60CB9E @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x28a77ea
$dynCall_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db16a
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15492
$ExecuteEvents_Execute_TisRuntimeObject_mA38648BA98D96A3CE0DA4CE52C77A35E29F8E952_gshared @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x2976723
$ExecuteEvents_Execute_TisIDeselectHandler_t1DAC043FE4AC6C9BD4E0128AD5CAC1C84F4AF661_mE10C0D18E3AD46419C7F1232AAE63443CA61EEF1(GameObject_t76FEDD663AB33C991A9C9A23129337651094216F*, BaseEventData_tE03A848325C0AE8E76C6CA15FD86395EBF83364F*, EventFunction_1_t761440E218DEDDDF4267213CA0E8B1C52C858690*, MethodInfo const*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x1748990
$dynCall_iiiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db188
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_iiiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15591
$StandaloneInputModule_ReleaseMouse_mC5C3083C356ACD5CD420A58662D99A6CACC5FAF5 @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x175e348
$dynCall_viiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db1d8
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_viiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15536
$StandaloneInputModule_ProcessMousePress_m24665E707FEF5C80719847D62A8A8AEABE27C6C5 @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x1763582
$dynCall_viii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db1e6
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_viii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15525
$StandaloneInputModule_ProcessMouseEvent_m8A8214EB9286BA31C18F515BCC3349DF740B2BBA @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x1761f4f
$dynCall_viii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db1e6
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_viii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15525
$StandaloneInputModule_ProcessMouseEvent_mCE1BA96E47D9A4448614CB9DAF5A406754F655DD @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x175ff1f
$dynCall_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db16a
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15492
$StandaloneInputModule_Process_mBD949CC45BBCAB5A0FAF5E24F3BB4C3B22FF3E81 @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x175f663
$VirtualActionInvoker0::Invoke(unsigned short, Il2CppObject*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x2ee9d69
$dynCall_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db16a
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_vii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15492
$EventSystem_Update_m9D0AC1A7236F0DA1CCA0A8FFE0D8D33D960D433C @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x174fb02
$RuntimeInvoker_TrueVoid_t4861ACF8F4594C3437BB48B6E56783494B843915(void (*)(), MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, void*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x39bfe80
$il2cpp::vm::Runtime::InvokeWithThrow(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x39f4f39
$dynCall_iiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db178
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
invoke_iiii @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:15547
$il2cpp::vm::Runtime::Invoke(MethodInfo const*, void*, void**, Il2CppException**) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x39f43a6
$il2cpp_runtime_invoke @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x39f656f
$ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x421b447
$MonoBehaviour::CallUpdateMethod(int) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42175d3
$MonoBehaviour::Update() @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42175e8
$void BaseBehaviourManager::CommonUpdate<BehaviourManager>() @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x3a87ba0
$BehaviourManager::Update() @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x3a87921
$InitPlayerLoopCallbacks()::UpdateScriptRunBehaviourUpdateRegistrator::Forward() @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x41f31f0
$ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x3a76f47
$ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x3a76fe3
$MainLoop() @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x40b4507
$dynCall_v @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.wasm:0x42db198
(anonymous) @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:1036
browserIterationFunc @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:9973
callUserCallback @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8163
runIter @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8224
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8138
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
requestAnimationFrame (async)
requestAnimationFrame @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8506
Browser_mainLoop_scheduler_rAF @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8040
Browser_mainLoop_runner @ AiSignpostingAnalysis.framework.js:8142
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? Post the full exception text. If you don't see `"audioByte Success"` it means `FromAudioClip` failed and this has nothing to do with BASE64

Comment: I see, yes. I don't see "audioByte Success"

Comment: Just a wild guess. But as far as I remember an array in C# is limited to Int32/Int64 entries (depending if the app is 32 or 64 bit). So may it be that your data is just too big to be stored into an array?

Comment: That could make sense, I’ll see if there’s a way to make the data smaller

Comment: @myst3rium but why would it be thrown then for [`System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.Double value)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-8.0#system-convert-toint32(system-double)) seems still kind of odd

Comment: Try building this with debug symbols and entire stack trace so you can better see where this exception is thrown at .. also disable the compression for now

Comment: @derHugo yes but due to the lack of information this is currently my best guess. Let's wait for further information from the error stack.

Comment: I added the stack trace and have updated the post with what came up

Comment: I re-wrote the script from scratch and it works now. There must be something in the old script that was throwing it